# Is there a way to combine the outputs of two bash commands?

Tags: bash

I am working to display users display name, date and time of login, and their default Bash shell. I can get each to print but I cannot find a way to get it to display line by line.

This is what I have tried to far. I have tried using that pipe, but so far putting them both in variables has been the closest thing yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

x="$(who | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d' ' -f1,3,4)"
y="$(cat /etc/passwd | tr -s [:print:] | cut -d':' -f7)"


echo $x  $y
```

For every user I have to display this:

```
username date of login time of login default bash shell
```

UPDATE:
The answers to other questions combine a single string together, this question is asking how to combine multiple lines of the WHO command, with the users default bash shell (which again is multiple lines). That is why I am asking here.

My sample output is to display the username, time and date of login, and the default bash shell for every logged in user like the `who` command does (so basically I want to take the `who` command, cut what I want out of it, and then add the user's default bash shell to the end). I have the two commands that give that to me but I need the default bash shell to be added onto each user displayed by the "who" command. Right now the program prints out all the users logged on and then after it prints them all out it prints the default shell.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "*I cannot find a way to get it to display line by line*"?

Comment: you can't expect that magically the outputs of two scripts will be aligned.

Comment: If you could, the answer would be `paste`. This is probably a common enough first exercise that we should be able to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty attempt.

```
who |
while read -r name _ time date _; do
    printf "%-12s %-14s %-14s %s\n" \
        "$name" "$time" "$date" \
        "$(getent passwd "$name" | cut -d: -f7)"
done
```

I am guessing as to what the fields are and what widths you want for the columns; the `who` tool's output is very system-dependent.

Comment: I understand what that's doing, but when it runs it does not display the default bash anywhere in the output. That's the part I have been stuck on the longest. All the fields and column widths are great though.

Comment: Oops, I mistyped the variable name. Updated now. Sorry about that. (I don't have `getent` so I stupidly didn't test that part.)

Comment: I don't understand why you call it "default bash"; each user has a shell defined (well, a "default shell", certainly)  and we look them up individually; it very well may not be Bash.

Comment: That makes since. I should have noticed that myself, but that displays it perfectly. I might mess around with some formatting and what I can do with it, but is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you for the help understanding.

Comment: Sure thing, have a wonderful weekend in the wondrous world of Bash.

Comment: You're right, I should have said default shell. That mistake totally slipped right through my mind, but yeah, that's  what I meant. All of the users currently on the server use Bash which is why I said that.